# Find if a QWidget belongs to a layout or not?

Tags: qt, layout, qwidget

Given a QWidget pointer, is it possible to determine if it belongs to any layout or not?
I don't have access to the layout, the only thing I have is the QWidget*
[Tricks and hacks are accepted :)]

Thank you.
CV

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `int QLayout::indexOf(QWidget * widget) const` ([link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlayout.html#indexOf)).

Or use `QLayout::itemAt(int index) const` recursively, if you want look at a child layouts too ([link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlayout.html#itemAt)).

Comment: Sry, I should have mentioned in the question. I don't have access to the layout, the only thing I am given is a QWidget*

Comment: How about `yourWidget->parentWidget()`? I think it should return null-pointer if there is no layouts.

Comment: consider you have a dockwidget, the dockwidget has a parent but doesn't belong to a layout. The only way I see is getting the parent widget's layout and checking if that layout contains my widget

Comment: Thanks, I have not thought about it.